# java.lang.RuntimeException in Google play console crash logs

Tags: android, crash, google-play-console

Following is the crash logs which is very frequent. These logs are obtained from google play console. But I am unable to track the base of the crash. Searched a lot on internet.
I am not using multidex in my app.

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver (ActivityThread.java:4060)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500 (ActivityThread.java:244)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1963)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:106)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:223)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7700)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:612)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:997)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass (BaseDexClassLoader.java:207)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:379)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:312)
  at android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateReceiver (AppComponentFactory.java:110)
  at androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory.instantiateReceiver (CoreComponentFactory.java:60)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver (ActivityThread.java:4053)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500 (ActivityThread.java:244)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1963)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:106)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:223)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7700)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:612)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:997)
```

Comment: I am just guessing but looks like the heavy optimization by proguard is the culprit here. There might be a 3rd party library in your project where some classes & stuff need to be excluded in the proguard rules' file.

Comment: But how do I know which class is missing.

Comment: Build & Run the app in Release mode and then try to see if you can get a more detailed logcat.. again I am just guessing.. the library you are looking for might have thrown some exception/error.

Comment: If the number of 3rd party libraries is quite limited, then I would suggest searching for similar issues on internet specifying the libraries' name one by one.